# How do I determine if SCOM has been installed on a particular Windows 7 enterprise server

Tags: windows-7, scom

How do I determine if SCOM has been installed on a particular Windows 7 enterprise computer that is being used as an IIS server and may need SCOM installed?

Comment: Well, you could check the SCOM management console. I don't think you'll find much though, as Windows 7 Server isn't a thing that exists.

Comment: well I have a box with Windows 7 enterprise that is hosting an iis server and may need to have SCOM installed.  Is that do-able?

Comment: So many questions raised. Why in heaven's name are you using Windows 7 as a web server? Are you the SCOM admin? If not, why aren't you asking that person? What version of SCOM? What are you trying to install - the management console, or a monitoring agent? There is a a SCOM agent for Windows 7 if you're using SCOM 2012.

Comment: So many questions raised. Why in heaven's name are you using Windows 7 as a web server? Are you the SCOM admin? If not, why aren't you asking that person? What version of SCOM? What are you trying to install - the management console, or a monitoring agent? There is a a SCOM agent for Windows 7 if you

Comment: I am a developer but I've been tasked with using SCOM.  I am not the administrator.  We have bought SCOM here but I have reason to believe it is not activated on "my" development "server" (which is really a Windows 7 computer).

Comment: Is there a way to verify if SCOM has or hasn't been installed on a particular machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to check that SCOM agent is installed on this machine (which literally means that this machine is monitored by SCOM) - it's enough to check that the following Windows service is installed: 
- HealthService (it's display name different for different versions of SCOM and might be a "Microsoft Monitoring Agent" or "System Center Management ")

If you need to check that the SCOM Management Server is installed on particular machine - you need to check another service: 
- OMSDK (display names is "System Center Data Access Service")

Good luck!